# Set max CPU limit for SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run queries on SQL server I often find that CPU % on server comes close to 100% . Is there anyway to set a max CPU % for SQL server just like the max memory setting . I find that without controlling CPU I can potentially crash a live server by running a report

Thanks

Comment: 100% CPU shouldn't crash your server...

Comment: I suspect http://dba.stackexchange.com is a better place to get a good answer to this question.

Comment: There is a discussion about this topic on the Microsoft forums, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a1e455c-171b-4c20-9016-59e890a759a9/limit-all-of-sql-to-90-cpu).